# How to use log4j2 file appender feature in unix environment

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am new to unix. I have below log4j2 config file. When I use this file in unix environment, the file app.log is not created. Could any one tell me how to redirect the logs to  file in unix environment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Configuration status="WARN">
        <Appenders>
             <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %method - %msg%n" />
            </Console>

            <File name="file" fileName="C:\Users\ppatrana\Desktop\app.log">

                    <!-- <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern> -->
                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %method -    %msg%n" />
            </File>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            </Root>
            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="file" />
            </Root>
         </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the filename :

```
<File name="file" fileName="/tmp/app.log">
```

More about linux filesystem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 1):

I think your real problem is that you have two root loggers. Try the following instead:

```
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

You also need to fix the filename as mentioned by @ToYonos.